# Sql service account password change for environment on Availability groups 2012

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, availability-groups, password, service-accounts

My current environment is on Availability groups sql 2012 with 1 Synchronous and 1 Asynchronous replica. Soon we need to change the sql service account passwords. 

Can any one suggest to me do I need to take any extra step(s) while changing the passwords? so that it will not disturb any existing settings or configurations?

Hope below steps are correct: 
1. Changing the sql service account password on primary server, then secondary servers and restarting them 
2. Ensure the data synchronization is properly running.

Answer (score 2):

I would do it in this order:

1. Change on Async Replica and restart SQL.

   - Make sure everything is still synchronizing after restart
2. Change Sync Replica and restart.

   - Make sure everything is still synchronizing after restart
3. Failover to Sync Replica
4. Change on former Primary (Current Sync Replica), and restart.

   - Make sure everything is still synchronizing after restart

You can then fail back to the old primary if need be, or leave on the Sync Replica if all things are equal.

Comment: Have you done the same before?

Comment: My answer was based on how you would apply updates/service packs.  But according to the advice here:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/09da6629-b494-4b99-a16b-694b845d0740/sql-service-password-change-in-alwayson-setup?forum=sqldisasterrecovery

no failover is needed, all replicas should be updated and restarted simoultaniously.

Comment: @ChadMattox Would you first set the AG to Manual Failover, and then re-set it to Automatic Failover at the end?